# I need to diving multiple sets of numbers by another set of numbers, as exactly as possible (as little waste as possible).

Tags: optimization, operations-research

I'm working in Excel and I have 2 separate lists. On the first is final length of goods to be cut, and how many of a given length. And on the second is manufactured lengths of goods (the lengths we received them at). I'm trying to find a way to efficiently calculate what cuts to take from what manufactured goods to result in little or no waste, but all I can think of is a lot of guessing and checking. There has to be a faster way to process all of this?

Side note: I'm not good at math beyond highschool, only ok at excel, and dont know any programming... So laymans terms me, please.

### Example:

```
Final Cuts (Inches):    Qty:         Mfg Length (Inches):        Qty:
                 280        7                            1804        7                          
                 49         3                            1796        3                 
                 79         6                            1776        1                 
                 174        11                           1416        4                     
                 330        7                                                       
                 169        18                                                        
                 287        4                                                            
                 146        9
```

Comment: Search term: *cutting stock problem*

Answer (score 1):

You can phrase this as a Linear Optimization Problem, and then use a LP program solver (many languages have packages to do so, I like cvxpy in python) to solve this. I'm pretty sure that a pure Excel solution doesn't exist.

The way I would phrase it as a LP problem is as follows: let $q_{ij}$ represent the quantity of pieces of type $i$ that are being made out of piece $j$. In the example you've presented, $i=1$ represents pieces of length $280$, $i=2$ of length $49$, etc, and $j=1\to 7$ represent pieces of length $1804$, $j=8\to 10$ pieces of length $1796$, etc.

Maximize $$q_{1,1}+q_{2,1}+\ldots+q_{8,1}+q_{1,2}+\ldots+q_{2,2}+\ldots+q_{8,2}+\ldots+q_{1,15}+\ldots+q_{8,15}$$

Under the constraints of the form:

$$280\cdot q_{1,1}+49\cdot q_{2,1}+79\cdot q_{3,1}+\ldots+146\cdot q_{8,1}\leq 1804$$
$$280\cdot q_{1,2}+49\cdot q_{2,2}+79\cdot q_{3,2}+\ldots+146\cdot q_{8,2}\leq 1804$$
$$\vdots$$
$$280\cdot q_{1,15}+49\cdot q_{2,15}+79\cdot q_{3,15}+\ldots+146\cdot q_{8,15}\leq 1416$$
$$q_{1,1}+q_{1,2}+\ldots+q_{1,15}\leq 7$$$$q_{2,1}+q_{2,2}+\ldots+q_{2,15}\leq 3$$$$\vdots$$$$q_{8,1}+q_{8,2}+\ldots+q_{8,15}\leq9$$

Comment: The $q$ variables need to be integers.

Comment: @prubin That's true, but integer optimization is hard, and any solution to this problem could suggest a similar integer solution.